# Как установить размеры камеры так, что-бы картинка отображалась одинаково на разных устройствах?

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть приложение на андроид, хочу установить размеры камеры так, что-бы картинка отображалась одинаково на разных устройствах.

Размер картинки 64х64.

Камера:

```
//В методе render(){
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 380, 780);
```

Сейчас картинка растягивается в ширину или в высоту, зависимо от устройства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует открыть для себя `Viewports`. Если кратко, то они позволят выбирать стратегии работы с разным разрешениями и соотношениями сторон. Более подробно все описано в Вики: https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/viewports

Ниже пример, основаный на шаблоне приложения, генерируемый gdx-setup

```
package libgdx;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

/** {@link com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener} implementation shared by all platforms. */
public class ViewPortExample extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture image;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        image = new Texture("libgdx.png");
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(760, 960, camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        camera.update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(image, 0, 0, 156, 32);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        image.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Ответьте на ещё 2 вопроса пожалуйста. 1.В чем разница между вашим способом и этим: camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2.5f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight / 2.5f); 2. Посоветуйте, какое разрешение указать для моей игры ? 480х800 или чуть больше, 720х1280 ?

Comment: На второй вопрос просто так не ответить, нужен контекст. Хотя бы знать идею игры. Для каких-то лучше использовать стейдж из Scene2d, например. Так или иначе, проще всего оперировать не реальными размерами, а игровыми.

Comment: Как я понимаю, для фона используется отдельный ViewPort, такой как StretchViewport ? А для компонентов использовать другой ?

Comment: Не уверен, я бы использовал один, а рабочую зону ограничил програмно. Есть вот такая статья, может поможет: https://habr.com/ru/articles/578884/